# PHP multidimensional array unknown variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble understanding this problem.

I have defined a multidimensional array but cannot echo values from it.

print_r($_POST) gives this:

```
Array
(
[title] => zxfvsdf
[purchaseDecision] => on
[optcolumn] => 2
[optrow] => 2
[opt] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => asd
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => vbn
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => yui
            )

    )

)
```

But echo $opt[0][0] returns 'undefined variable: opt'.

I am sure I am missing something quite basic...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
echo $_POST['opt'][0][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
print_r($_POST['opt'][0][0]);
```

**Because** `opt` is in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

it should be: `$_POST['opt'][0][0];`

if the `register_globals` is disabled in php (which is a good thing and is by default disabled) variables are not assigned from the request.

Comment: What an unbelievably stupid error to have made. Sorry! And thank you

Answer (score 1):

Define `$opt = $_POST['opt'];` before using `$opt[0][0]`